# How can we handle deep links in flutter with Get X for go to Custom pages of the application?

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking, flutter-getx

How can we handle deep links in flutter with Get X for go to Custom pages of the application ?

By default, by adding the desired address to the Android Manifest file:

```
        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="flutterbooksample.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="flutterbooksample.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

when the application opens, the main page of application will be displayed to us.

I am looking to implement this I can direct the user to **any** page of the application that is needed. A practical example is to pay on the web page and return to the application. When we return, we should show the user a message about the status of the payment, not direct the user to the first page of the application.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no @Infaz

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the response

Comment: Hi, @Infaz here is an answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Huseyn, I will try this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the page routing in your app, when you process the deeplink.

In my apps, I usually use uni_links (https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) and in my `main.dart`, I have something like this:

```
StreamSubscription<String> _subUniLinks;

@override
initState() {
    super.initState();
    // universal link setup
    initUniLinks();
}

Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    try {
        final String initialLink = await getInitialLink();
        await processLink(initialLink);
    } on PlatformException {
    }
    _subUniLinks = linkStream.listen(processLink, onError: (err) {});
}

processLink(String link) async {
    // parse link and decide what to do:
    // - use setState
    // - or use Navigator.pushReplacement
    // - or whatever mechanism if you have in your app for routing to a page
}

@override
dispose() {
    if (_subUniLinks != null) _subUniLinks.cancel();
    super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: where this linkStream come from ?

Comment: old question but linkSream comes from the same package: uni_links

Answer (score 1):

my method is alike as Didier Prophete answer, but I use this in singleTon class, call in main.dart (above return MyApp line)

```
await DeepLinkService().initialDeepLinks();
```

but I don't know how to cancel and dispose the StreamSubscription

```
StreamSubscription? _sub;

Future<void> initialDeepLinks() async {
    try {
      //init deeplink when start from inactive
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
      if (initialLink != null) {
        await _handleDeepLink(initialLink);
      }

      //Check deeplink in foreground/background
      _sub = linkStream.listen((String? link) async {
        if (link != null) {
          await _handleDeepLink(link);
        }
      }, onError: (e) {
        DebugLog().show(e.toString());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      DebugLog().show(e.toString());
    }
  }

  // Handle the deep link
  Future<void> _handleDeepLink(String link) async {
    Uri deepLink = Uri.parse(link);
    String path = deepLink.path;
    DebugLog().show('open app from deeplink: $deepLink with path: $path');

    //Switch the path then navigate to destinate page
  }
```